# Telerik RadNumericTextBox - flicker when text right aligned

Tags: asp.net, telerik

Say that a RadNumericTextBox is defined like this in an ASP.NET 2.0 aspx page :

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="idNum" runat="server" 
Type="Currency" MinValue="0"  Value="0"  >
<NumberFormat DecimalDigits="2" />
<EnabledStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
</telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
```

Note that it is set to be right aligned. 
Now, it works fine, but when the control displays on the page, you can initially see it draw the text inside the textbox left aligned. After this fraction of a second, the text becomes right aligned. Anyone got any workarounds to prevent this flickering ? (Note that there is no flickering when the control is set to be left aligned.)

EDIT (Version info) :
RadControls for ASPNET AJAX Q1 2008, version 2008.1
(Used on ASP.NET 2.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose this depends on the page load time and the numeric textbox initialization. I think that the current Telerik AJAX version is Q2 2010, you can try it out to compare or use [RadInputManager](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/input/examples/radinputmanager/firstlook/defaultcs.aspx) with standard right-aligned textboxes for a change.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
    <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="ntxtApprovedAmount" runat="server" Skin="" CssClass="cssTextBox" MinValue="0" Display="false" Width="115px">
    <EnabledStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
```